# Rails cancancan fetching records for specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I need to fetch only specific records from the database on a certain condition using CanCanCan. This is my data model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions_users
end

class RegionsUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :region
end

class Region < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions_users
  has_many :sites
end

class Site < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :offers
end

class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
end
```

For example, a user is assigned to two regions, which means that the user 
`user.regions_users` returns and array of two RegionsUser [RegionsUser1, RegionsUser2]. RegionsUser1 belongs to a Region A and RegionsUser2 belongs to Region B so if I am logged in as the user I am a region user that can oversee the data belonging to those regions. Now, I need to display Offers that belong to those regions (Region A and Region B). That means, that the user cannot access an offer belonging to a region other than Region A and Region B, so accessing `/offers/3` should raise `Access Denied` error.

I can pull the regions from RegionsUser:

```
region_ids = user.regions_users.pluck(:regions_id)
```

and then the Offers:

```
Offer.joins(:site).where(sites: { region_id: region_ids })
```

I read about defining abilities using a block described [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks)

```
can :update, Project, ["priority < ?", 3] do |project|
  project.priority < 3
end
```

but I can't think of any solution for my case. I would appreciate any ideas.

***UPDATE***

This kinda works, but instead of displaying Access Denied page it raises 404 Page Not Found error.

`offers_controller.rb`

```
def offer
  @offer ||= Offer.accessible_by(current_ability).find(params[:id])
end
```

`ability.rb`

```
if user.region_user?
  region_ids = user.regions_users.pluck(:region_id)
  can :read, Offer, site: { region_id: region_ids }
end
```

***UPDATE 2***

I could catch `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and `raise CanCanCan::AccessDenied` but that is a workaround. I would expect CanCanCan to handle the authorization part. I could just pull the records in the controller and raise an expcetion but that doesn't really relate to CanCanCan, does it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `load_and_authorize_resource` in your controllers. I don't think it will raise the

`raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new("Not authorized!", :read, Article)` unless you do that.
The `accessible_by(currrent_ability)` simply scoped the result set to those defined in your ability file

Comment: I do `load_and_authorize_resource in my controller. I don't think the scope accessible_by does anything more than a regular rails scope, yes, I agree. I've figured this out. It does not raise AccessDenied error so I'd be better off writing my own RegionUserOffersQuery and raise CanCan::AccessDenied in my controller.